# Updating GWT CellTable row style programatically

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I am trying to update a row style for on mouse hover.

```
mappings.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<MappingInstructionVO>() {

      @Override 
      public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<MappingInstructionVO> event) { 
        if (BrowserEvents.MOUSEOVER.equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) { 
           mappings.getRowElement(event.getValue().getExecutionOrder()).getStyle().setBorderColor("Red"); 
      } 
});
```

I am able wo get row content successfully using:

```
mappings.getRowElement(event.getValue().getExecutionOrder() - 1).getInnerText());
```

Any idea why

```
mappings.getRowElement(event.getValue().getExecutionOrder()).getStyle().setBorderColor("Red");
```

has no effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid has `dataGridHoveredRow` style defined in its default `DataGrid.Resources`. One option is to override this style in your own ClientBundle.

Otherwise, try

```
.getStyle().setProperty("border", "1px solid red");
```

EDIT:

You must set "border-collapse: collapse" on your DataGrid.

From the CSS2 specification:

> In [the border-collapse: separate model], each cell has an individual
>   border. [...] Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups cannot have
>   borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those
>   elements).

Comment: No your recommendation didn't work. Thanks for the reply, though.

I also tried .getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);

in addition to what I have but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you also provide the link, if its handy. Actually I want to see what all properties are (not)supported. I would like to add box-shadow if border is not supported.

Comment: "CSS2 specification", first result on Google. For table borders: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders

Comment: Thanks Andrei, you have been very helpful. I was stuck at it for a very long time.